# Angular 2 - Setting Timeout in a Service

Tags: angular

I want to create a delay in a Service of my Angular 2 project for testing purposes. More specifically, I want the call of

```
this.myIatreioService.getIatreia()
```

to be delayed for 1 sec. My service is the following:

```
@Injectable()
export class IatreioService {
   private headers = new Headers();

   constructor(private http: Http) {
       let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
       if (token) {
         this.headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token });
       }
   }

   getIatreia(): Observable<Iatreio[]> {
       return this.http
                  .get('http://localhost:3000/iatreia', { headers: this.headers })
                  .map(response => response.json() as Iatreio[]);
   }

} // end of Service
```

I have tried to implement setTimeout function, but it doesn't work:

```
getIatreia(): Observable<Iatreio[]> {
   setTimeout(() => {   
      return this.http
                 .get('http://localhost:3000/iatreia', { headers: this.headers })
                 .map(response => response.json() as Iatreio[]);
   }, 1000);
}
```

Is there a solution for my problem?? If not, can I put setTimeout() either in Component or in Server?? Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use the [delay operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-delay):

```
return this.http
           .get('http://localhost:3000/iatreia', { headers: this.headers })
           .map(response => response.json() as Iatreio[])
           .delay(1000);
```

Comment: @Pengyy that wouldn't change anything. if you put it first, the http response is received, then emitted after 1 second, then mapped to JSON. If you put it last, the http response is received, mapped to JSON, then emitted after 1 second. In both cases, you get JSON emitted after 1 second.

Comment: delay() cannot be found. What should I import??

Comment: The delay operator, as any other operator: import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Observable use the timeout operator as below

```
return this.http
                 .get('http://localhost:3000/iatreia', { headers: this.headers })
                 .map(response => response.json() as Iatreio[])
                 .timeout(200, 'Timeout has occurred.');
```

Note: time specified is in **milliseconds**

Comment: timeout() cannot be found. What should I import??

Comment: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout';`

Comment: I believe the title means 'timeout' as in 'setTimeout', as it's suggested in another answer.

Comment: no after that duration of 200 seconds service call will be cancelled

Answer (score 0):

with httpClient you can do something like:

```js
myService() {
        return this.httpClient.get('http://.to.co/')
            .timeout(200, timeout)
            .map((data) => {
                return data;
            })
            .catch((error: Response) => {
                return (error);
            });
    }
```