# Angular 2 equivalent for $timeout

Tags: javascript, angular, timeout

I have to use (large amounts of) existing code in an Angular 2 environment. That code makes extensive use of the [`$timeout` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) from AngularJS 1.x. As opposed to various other AngularJS 1.x services that are used in the code, I am having a hard time finding a information about an Angular 2 equivalent for the `$timeout` service.

The [Angular docs](https://angular.io/api) do not seem to contain any mention of a service with `timeout`-something in its name. The article [*Upgrading from AngularJS*](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade) does mention the scenario I am facing:

> Maybe you want access to AngularJS's built-in services like `$location` or `$timeout`.

Unfortunately, the article does not actually explain how to access those particular services, as the subsequent example `HeroesService` assumes a service without any dependencies supplied by AngularJS 1.x.

Articles such as [this one](http://www.codelord.net/2015/10/14/angular-nitpicking-differences-between-timeout-and-settimeout/) suggest using the native [`setTimeout` function](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.setTimeout.html) does not live up to the capabilities of the `$timeout` services, either.

**How can I reproduce the `$timeout` functionality in the Angular 2 environment?**

EDIT: As has been noted in the answers, the drawbacks of the native `setTimeout` function are not relevant when using Angular 2. In that case, if I had the full `$q` from AngularJS 1.x, I could replicate the `$timeout` function roughly like this:

```
function $timeout(fn, delay) {
    var result = $q.defer();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $q.when(fn()).then(function (v) {
            result.resolve(v);
        });
    }, delay);
    return result.promise;
}
```

Comment: http://blog.neilni.com/2016/03/27/settimeout-in-angular-2/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44096451/8317956

Comment: @slacker: The `delay` operator appears to return an `Observable`, so I would have to get rid of that to elevate things back to proper promises. The first link with the pointer to timers looks promising, though; maybe I can craft a wrapper that appears like the original `$timeout` based upon that. I just wonder, why can't I find `timer` in the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/api)?

Comment: Mapper - know it was 4 years ago but 'delay' in the code above is a parameter (# of ms), not an operator.

Comment: @jessewolfe: Of course, don't know what I was thinking. Maybe I was thinking of "operand", which comes a little bit closer? Pff ... thanks for pointing it out, though, lest other readers get confused.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` native function. There is no need to use special services in Angular anymore. This is due to the introduction of [zones](https://indepth.dev/posts/1135/i-reverse-engineered-zones-zone-js-and-here-is-what-ive-found), specifically [NgZone](https://indepth.dev/posts/1059/do-you-still-think-that-ngzone-zone-js-is-required-for-change-detection-in-angular).

> Articles such as this one suggest using the native setTimeout function
> does not live up to the capabilities of the $timeout services, either.

Why makes you say so? The main task of `$timeout` service was to start digest after the delayed function is executed. You can see it from the sources:

```
function $TimeoutProvider() {
  this.$get = ['$rootScope', '$browser', '$q', '$$q', '$exceptionHandler',
    function($rootScope,   $browser,   $q,   $$q,   $exceptionHandler) {

        timeoutId = $browser.defer(function() {
          try {
            deferred.resolve(fn.apply(null, args));
          } catch (e) {
          ...

          if (!skipApply) $rootScope.$apply();  <-------------------- here
        }, delay);
```

In Angular `zone.js` intercepts all async operations and starts change detection in Angular which is [kind of enhanced version of digest](https://indepth.dev/posts/1136/angulars-digest-is-reborn-in-the-newer-version-of-angular).

If you need to replicate the `$timeout`, you can roughly do it like this:

```
function $timeout(fn, delay, ...args) {
  let timeoutId;

  $timeout.cancel = $timeout.cancel || function (promise) {
    if (promise && promise.$$timeoutId in $timeout.promises) {
      $timeout.promises[promise.$$timeoutId][1]('canceled');
      delete $timeout.promises[promise.$$timeoutId];
      return clearTimeout(promise.$$timeoutId);
    }
    return false;
  };

  $timeout.promises = $timeout.promises || {};

  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
      try {
        resolve(fn.apply(null, args));
      } catch (e) {
        reject(e);
      } finally {
        delete $timeout.promises[promise.$$timeoutId];
      }
    }, delay);

    $timeout.promises[timeoutId] = [resolve, reject];
  });

  promise.$$timeoutId = timeoutId;

  return promise;
}

// some basic testing

$timeout((v) => {
  console.log('a', v);
}, 2000, 7);

const promise = $timeout(() => {
  console.log('b');
}, 3000);

promise.catch((reason) => {
  console.log(reason);
});

$timeout.cancel(promise);
```

Comment: "Why makes you say so?" - well, the linked article highlights some caveats when it comes to doing things after timeouts that need to be digested by Angular.

Comment: In any case, I am not sure how to use `setTimeout` to create something like `$timeout`. I want to get back a promise, so in AngularJS 1.x, I'd probably need to create a deferred and resolve it within the function passed to `setTimeout`. The problem is, `$q.defer()` is missing in Angular 2, as well.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, the article you mentioned talks about the difference in the context of AngularJS. What it says doesn't apply to Angular. Angular uses `zone.js` to intercept async operations and run digest

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, show the code from AngularJS in your question details you're referring to that uses `$.defer()`

Comment: I have updated my question to include an example for recreating the `$timeout` functionality.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, I've added the implementation to my answer.

Comment: Thank you; I will accept your answer as this is already helpful. It will be somewhat more complicated, as I also want to replicate the `$timeout.cancel` function (and therefore have to attach some marker to the resulting promise that identifies which timeout should be cancelled), but in general, this has brought me on the right track.

Comment: thanks, yeah, just wanted to say it's missing `cancel` and `arguments` handling. You can do it on your own. If not, let me know, I'll add these. Or I'll add these a bit later anyways for future reference

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, added full implementation. Check my updated answer